# What is an efficient way of handling Child Component States from a Parent Component map?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks, state, react-state-management

I want to have a Parent component which can add a number of Child components - pressing a button will add a new Child Object to state, which subsequently renders the Child component through a `children.map(c => ...)` function.

`Child` is a component that renders a dropdown menu to select an option - based on the selected option, additional inputs appear (e.g. 'Person' renders 'First Name', 'Last Name'). The user should be able to add multiple `Child` components, and update them easily. The problem I have is value/state storage:

1. Storing the values of each `Child` component in the `Parent` is easy to do, but the state will reupdate every child due to the `children.map` render method. This would happen on each key-press/value change etc.
2. I recognise it is bad practice to store Components in state, so have tried rendering these through the objects.
3. There could be any number of `Child` components (1, 5, 100...)

Example files:

Parent.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  /**
   * This should be an array of objects:
   *
   * {
   *  childType: person | animal | city,
   *  values: (one of the below)
   * }
   *
   * personValue: {
   *  firstName: string
   *  lastName: string
   * }
   *
   * animalValue: {
   *  animalType: string;
   *  age: number
   * }
   *
   * cityValue: {
   *  name: string
   *  population: number
   * }
   *
   */
  const [children, setChildren] = useState([]);

  const defaultChild = {
    childType: "",
    childId: Math.random(),
    values: {},
  };

  const addChild = () => {
    setChildren([...children, defaultChild]);
  };

  const handleUpdateChildType = (childId, newChildType) => {
    let newChildren = [...children];
    let childIndex = children.findIndex((f) => f.childId === childId);
    let child = children[childIndex];
    child.childType = newChildType;
    newChildren[childId] = child;
    setChildren(newChildren);
  };

  const handleUpdateChildValues = (childId, field, newValue) => {
    let newChildren = [...children];
    let childIndex = children.findIndex((f) => f.childId === childId);
    let child = children[childIndex];
    child.values[field] = newValue;
    newChildren[childId] = child;
    setChildren(newChildren);
  };

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <div>
        <h2>Parent</h2>
        <button onClick={addChild}>Add Child</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {children.map((child) => (
          <Child
            childId={child.childId}
            childType={child.childType}
            values={child.values}
            updateChildType={handleUpdateChildType}
            updateChildValues={handleUpdateChildValues}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Child.jsx:

```
import React from "react";

const Child = (props) => {
  const { childId, childType, values, updateChildType, updateChildValues } =
    props;

  console.log(`Child ${childId} rerendering...`);

  const handleChildTypeChange = (e) => {
    updateChildType(childId, e.target.value);
  };

  const handleChildValuesChange = (field, newValue) => {
    updateChildValues(childId, field, newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Child</h3>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="childType">Choose an option</label>
          <select
            name="childType"
            id={`${Math.random()}`}
            onChange={handleChildTypeChange}
            value={childType}
          >
            <option value="person">person</option>
            <option value="animal">animal</option>
            <option value="city">city</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          {childType === "person" ? (
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="firstName">First name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                value={values.firstName}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleChildValuesChange("firstName", e.target.value)
                }
              ></input>
              <label htmlFor="lastName">Last name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="lastName"
                name="lastName"
                value={values.lastName}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleChildValuesChange("lastName", e.target.value)
                }
              ></input>
            </div>
          ) : childType === "animal" ? (
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="animalType">Animal Type:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="animalType"
                name="animalType"
                value={values.animalType}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleChildValuesChange("animalType", e.target.value)
                }
              ></input>
              <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                id="age"
                name="age"
                value={values.age}
                onChange={(e) => handleChildValuesChange("age", e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
          ) : childType === "city" ? (
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                value={values.name}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleChildValuesChange("name", e.target.value)
                }
              ></input>
              <label htmlFor="population">Population:</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                id="population"
                name="population"
                value={values.population}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleChildValuesChange("population", e.target.value)
                }
              ></input>
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Edit: The `Parent` component requires the state as additional logic would be included in it, such as validating the object and making an API call with the generated state. I've omitted these from the code to keep the code compact.

Comment: Create a wrapper component which accepts the children as props, and render it using [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Comment: @jsejcksn Could you elaborate on this please, as I don't think it works? The props of the Wrapper component (i.e. children) will be changed due to the map, so the Wrapper will re-render, and subsequently re-render all the `Child` components.

Comment: Before going forward: you don't show using any of the state in the parent. Is it actually needed there for some use? If not, then you only need to generate a new unique ID for each child when adding it to the list (for the mapping [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)), and then map those unique IDs to the Child components, allowing them to create and maintain their own states. If you do need to access the state in the parent, please update your question with how/why so that a potential answer can address the details of what's really happening.

Comment: I've put an edit at the bottom - I omitted any other logic but the resulting object would be used elsewhere in a wider application and sent off to an API.

Additionally, I've created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-child-components-rerendering-pfm4ec) with some progress with your suggestion, but this is creating a peculiar issue where the children state object is appearing empty in the `Parent` and `Wrapper` when changing one of the `Child` dropdown menu's...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. After reviewing the details of your question more thoroughly and seeing the sandbox, I realize that my initial comment was uninformed; here are some observations: Memoizing each mapped child component with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) is the solution to addressing your explicitly stated concern regarding rendering optimization. However, preceding that concern: (...cont.)

Comment: The sandbox code you've shared indicates that you don't yet have a fundamental understanding of memoization concepts in React (e.g. object identity, [dependency lists](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies), [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), etc.). That understanding is critical to managing the data flow in the app code you've shared. (...cont.)

Comment: Beyond that, there are issues unrelated to memoization in the sample code (one example: the need to initialize/reset an item's state in a "type" change operation). The sum of what I've described so far is out of scope for a single question on Stack Overflow. (And perhaps the application-specific code is better suited for a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).) I suggest spending time reviewing core memoization concepts in React and JavaScript before proceeding with your work.

Comment: I'm not voting to close your question as it stands (because it is focused), but your rendering optimization concern won't become relevant until the other memoization problems are addressed.